# Why does trying to install busybox-initscripts on an alpine container results in an error?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I try to dockerize PiVPN in a alpine docker container.

My current Dockerfile looks like this

```dockerfile
FROM alpine
RUN apk upgrade --available
RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    bash \
    curl
RUN apk add busybox-initscripts
RUN curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash
```

The step to install busybox-initscripts results in the error

```
#7 0.441   busybox-initscripts (no such package):
#7 0.441 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#7 0.480     required by: world[busybox-initscripts]
#7 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add busybox-initscripts]: exit code: 1
------
 > [5/5] RUN apk add busybox-initscripts:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add busybox-initscripts]: exit code: 1
```

Both the [pivpn docs](https://docs.pivpn.io/install/#alpine) and [alpine linux](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/busybox-initscripts) try to convince me the package should exist

Comment: `busybox-initscripts (no such package):` so? There is no question in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listing a package in the alpine 3.3 release. The latest tag of alpine is currently pointing to 3.17 where this package does not exist. https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=busybox-initscripts&branch=v3.17&repo=&arch=x86_64&maintainer=